# USB sound on PC when plugging laptop charger into the socket

Tags: electrical-engineering, electronics

Sometimes I hear my PC making the *USB - connected device* sound when I plug in my laptop charger into the socket.

By USB *connected device* I mean the sound that it usually makes when I connect something through the USB port.

I am not exactly sure what causes this sound.

Comment: Did the response below help you find a solution .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a windows machine the sound can be managed via a the control panel.

[image: Windows Sound Control Panel]

Change Sound Settings

[image: Windows Sounds Settings]